# Fail at ROS2 IDL generation

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to add support for ROS2 IDL generation with Rust.

It happens to work only when `find_package` are declared in packages containing message definitions with
`find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)` first.

It means that in `std_msgs` for example, the following will make the whole generation work.

```
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(builtin_interfaces REQUIRED)
```

While this will fail :

```
find_package(builtin_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
```

With the following error.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/crystal/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_target_interfaces.cmake:44 (message):
  rosidl_target_interfaces() the second argument 'std_msgs' concatenated with
  the third argument 'rosidl_typesupport_c' using double underscores must be
  a valid target name
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/sisyphe/Projects/tests/ros2_rust_ws/install/share/rosidl_generator_rs/cmake/rosidl_generator_rs_generate_interfaces.cmake:200 (rosidl_target_interfaces)
  /opt/ros/crystal/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:38 (include)
  /opt/ros/crystal/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:280 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)
```

The file [rosidl_generator_rs_generate_interfaces.cmake](https://github.com/lelongg/ros2_rust/blob/std_msgs_fail/rosidl_generator_rs/cmake/rosidl_generator_rs_generate_interfaces.cmake) generating this error can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/lelongg/ros2_rust/tree/std_msgs_fail).

I seems that the required target does not exist at the right time but I don't know what dependency to add to fix this.

I don't understand the whole ROS2 IDL generation process yet and any help on how to be more knowledgeable on this matter might be useful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315189/fail-at-ros2-idl-generation/) by [lelongg](https://answers.ros.org/users/33223/lelongg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-02-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-02-11**:
Trying to build a workspace containing the referenced repository works fine for me (at least until `rclrs_examples` which fails to invoke `cargo` which I don't have installed). Please describe the exact steps when you see the error.

**Comment by [lelongg](https://answers.ros.org/users/33223/lelongg/) on 2019-02-12**:
You're right, the repository compiles because I have manually edited all message packages to reorder `find_package`.

I have created a dedicated branch [std_msgs_fail](https://github.com/lelongg/ros2_rust/tree/std_msgs_fail) which reproduce the issue and should not compile.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-02-19**:
I just tried to build a workspace using the `std_msgs_fail` branch and it passed (at least as far as the previous build) without a problem.

**Comment by [lelongg](https://answers.ros.org/users/33223/lelongg/) on 2019-02-19**:
I've just figured that I cannot reproduce my issue without the `--merge-install` argument on `colcon build`, which I was always using until now. Could you try again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With `colcon build --merge-install` (for performance `--packages-up-to std_msgs`) I can reproduce the failure.

The problem is that when your code generator is being executed (the logic in `rosidl_generator_rs_generate_interfaces.cmake`) it tries to depend on the `rosidl_typesupport_c` target. But your package didn't make sure that `rosidl_typesupport_c` was `find_package`-ed. That needs to happen before you register your own message generator in `rosidl_generator_rs_extras`. Otherwise the `rosidl_typesupport_c` might only be found later and therefore will only try to generate its code *after* your package has done so.

The easiest fix is to insert the following line in `rosidl_generator_rs-extras.cmake.in` before calling the macro:

```
find_package(rosidl_typesupport_c REQUIRED)
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lelongg](https://answers.ros.org/users/33223/lelongg/) on 2019-02-20**:
Nice! I wasn't able to figure where I should add it, so it's was there! Thanks